# Spurious spaces in tabular environment with siunitx and percent symbol

Tags: tables, siunitx

I keep getting spurious spaces when I use the siunitx in a tabular environment in the presence of a percent (%) symbol. I am trying to align at the decimal point.

My code is:

```
\begin{tabular}{lS}
    One   & 0.1234\percent \tabularnewline
    Two   & 1.234\percent  \tabularnewline
    Three & 12.34\percent  \tabularnewline
    Four  & 123.4\percent  \tabularnewline
    Five  & 1234\percent   \tabularnewline
    Six   & 1234.0\percent \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

and the resulting output is:

[image: Result]

The decimal-point alignment is working but the percent symbol has increasing number of spaces as the whole number part of the number increases.

Is there a way of removing these spaces easily, so that the percent symbols appear right after the number? I can hack it by having the percent symbol appear as a unit in a separate column, i.e.

```
\begin{tabular}{lSs}
    One & 0.1234 & \percent \tabularnewline
```

but is there a way of having the percent symbol right next to the number as it appears for One, Two and Three above, e.g.

```
   0.1234%
1234%
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you call a spurious space is actually a conscious design decision; see p. 81 of the user guide of the `siunitx` package.

Comment: Or perhaps it is the problem stated in page 45 of siunitx documentation? (btw, my `siunitx` guide has only 60 pages)

Comment: I forgot to add: If you must have a percent symbol without any space between the numbers and the symbols, (a) use the `\%` control sequence instead of `\percent` and (b) issue the command `\sisetup{input-symbols=\%}` ahead of the table in question.

Comment: @JLDiaz: Which version of `siunitx` is installed on your system? (The one on my system is numbered `2.5e`.)

Answer (score 6):

The `S` column is intended for numbers *only*: it is not the same as using both arguments to `\SI`. Normally, I would suggest either using two separate columns and remove the inter-column padding uisng `@{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=4.4]@{}s}
    One   &    0.1234 & \percent \\
    Two   &    1.234  & \percent \\
    Three &   12.34   & \percent \\
    Four  &  123.4    & \percent \\
    Five  & 1234      & \percent \\
    Six   & 1234.0    & \percent \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

or even better adding this information to the header

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=4.4]}
  \toprule
    & {Value/\si{\percent}} \\
  \midrule
    One   &    0.1234 \\
    Two   &    1.234  \\
    Three &   12.34   \\
    Four  &  123.4    \\
    Five  & 1234      \\
    Six   & 1234.0    \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you do want the input as given, you need `free-standing-units`, alter the definition of `\percent` and fiddle a bit with the alignment settings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{free-standing-units}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product={}]{\percent}{\%}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=4.4,table-align-text-post=false]}
    One   &    0.1234\percent \\
    Two   &    1.234 \percent \\
    Three &   12.34  \percent \\
    Four  &  123.4   \percent \\
    Five  & 1234     \percent \\
    Six   & 1234.0   \percent \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `siunitx` version 2.x: update the question if a version 1.x answer is needed!

Comment: Thank you all. I have version 1.x at the moment so I am updating to the latest siunitx, and will then attempt the above fix/es. If that fails, then I might ask for version 1.x fix.

Comment: @salestial If you are getting `siunitx` v2 from CTAN, you _must_ also get the latest `l3kernel` and `l3packages`. They have to 'match' and were all updated 48 h ago!

Comment: It works! It was indeed a version problem - version 1.3 was not even supporting (or was throwing an error) keyword arguments to `S`. All sorted now though - thanks all!